# Одновременное обновление родительской и дочерней таблицы по ключу

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть `table1` c `tab1_id primary key`  и `table2` c `tab1_id foreign key`. 
Нужно изменить `table1.tab1_id`.
При попытке изменить `tab1_id` в любой из таблиц ругается на нарушение целостности:

```
Update table1 set tab1_id = 22 where tab1_id = 11
```

> ORA-02292: "обнаружена порожденная запись"

```
Update table2 set tab1_id = 22 where tab1_id = 11
```

> ORA-02292: "Исходный ключ не найден".

Можно ли сделать апдейт сразу в 2 таблицы? Или как обойти это ограничение не внося ограничение в структуру таблицы (без alter table)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

шаг 1. выключаем внешние ключи(`alter table disable constraint`)

шаг 2. обновляем данные для обоих таблиц(`update table1 set tab1_id = .., update table2`)

шаг 3. включаем обратно внешние ключи(`alter table enable constraint`)

**Вариант 2:**

Объявляем наш `constraint` как `defferable`.

```
alter table table2 
add constraint constraint_name foreign key (tab1_id)
references table1(tab1_id) deferrable;
```

Обновление таблицы выполняем в PL\SQL блоке:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'set constraint constraint_name deferred';
  update table1 ..;
  update table2 ..;
  commit;
end;
```

**PS:**

У вас что-то странное с архитектурой БД. При правильной архитектуре не должно возникать ситуации, когда необходимо править `ID`.

Answer (score 6):

Если возник такой вопрос, значит скорее всего вследствии ошибки "поломан" не один единственный ключ. В этом случае, надо:

- ограничить доступ к БД переведя её в [*restricted session mode*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/start.htm#ADMIN11155)
- [*отключить внешние ключи*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#i2103997) с `alter table t2 modify constraint t2_fk1 disable;`
- изменить ключи
- снова включить ключи и перевести БД в нормальный режим.

---

Если это всё-таки единичный случай, можно сделать *move* (скопировать-удалить в одной транзакции), например:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key);
create table t2 (
    id number, memo varchar2 (32), constraint t2_fk1 foreign key (id) references t1(id)
);

insert into t1 values (11); 
insert into t2 select 11, 'memo'||rownum from xmlTable ('1 to 2');

create or replace procedure moveKeys (oldId number, newId number) is
    newRow t1%rowtype;  
begin
    select * into newrow from t1 where id = oldId;
    newRow.id := newId;
    insert into t1 values newRow;
    update t2 set id = newId where id = oldId;
    delete t1 where id = oldId;  
end;
/
exec moveKeys (11, 22); commit;

select * from t1 join t2 on t2.id = t1.id;

        ID         ID MEMO                           
---------- ---------- --------------------------------
        22         22 memo1                           
        22         22 memo2
```

Comment: Отличный ответ!